# Vue.js component with checkbox ID conflicts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a custom Vue component (vcheck) that has a checkbox with a label:

```
<input 
    v-model="val" 
    type='checkbox' 
    :true-value="trueValue" 
    :false-value="falseValue"
    id="v-check"
>
<label for="v-check">{{val == trueValue ? displayChecked : displayUnchecked}}</label>
```

but the problem is when I have multiple instances (in the parent component), the IDs of the checkboxes clash:

```
<vcheck v-model="val1" display-checked="Yes" display-unchecked="No"></vcheck>
<vcheck v-model="val2" display-checked="Tested" display-unchecked="Untested"></vcheck>
```

So when i click the 2nd checkbox label, the 1st one changes (since they both have the same ID). At the moment I removed IDs and just using `@click` event on labels. But is there a way to generate unique IDs for every instance of the component?

Answer (score 1):

One option can be to pass the id also as props to vcheck:

```
<vcheck v-model="val1" display-checked="Yes" display-unchecked="No" id="123">
</vcheck>
```

and use that for checkbox:

```
<input 
    v-model="val" 
    type='checkbox' 
    :true-value="trueValue" 
    :false-value="falseValue"
    :id="id"
>
```

I will recommend to  make the id prop [mandatory](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation) if you use this.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but I would like to keep the declaration as minimal as possible. Plus it requires keeping track of IDs anyway.